# how to combine two different tables into one

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table with below structure

```sql
INSERT INTO reservation(rid, WHEEL_CHAIR, blind) VALUES (1,8,9)
INSERT INTO reservation(rid, WHEEL_CHAIR, blind) VALUES (2,11,12)
    
SELECT id,
       WHEEL_CHAIR,
       blind
FROM   reservation
```

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 9 |
| 2 | 11 | 12 |

This gives a count of people who need wheel chair(8) and count of blind people (9) and I have a `disability` table where the details of the disability is explained

```sql
INSERT INTO disability(hid, code, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (5,'aa', 'wheel chair')
INSERT INTO disability(hid, code, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (7,'bl', 'blind')
```

I want to club the above 2 tables and need to have a new table with the data

```sql
insert into newTable( newID,hid,count) values (1,5,8) 
insert into newTable( newID,hid,count) values (1,7,9)
insert into newTable( newID,hid,count) values (2,5,11) 
insert into newTable( newID,hid,count) values (2,7,12)
```

here 5 and 7 are the disability ids and 8,9,11,12 are the count of the blind people or the count of people who need a wheel chair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpivot the `reservation` table and then `INNER JOIN` it to the `disabilities` table:

```sql
SELECT rid AS newId, hid, cnt
FROM   reservation
       UNPIVOT (
         cnt FOR description IN (
           wheel_chair AS 'wheel chair',
           blind AS 'blind'
         )
       ) r
       INNER JOIN disability d
       ON (d.description = r.description)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE reservation(rid, WHEEL_CHAIR, blind) AS
  SELECT 1,8,9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,11,12 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE disability(hid, code, DESCRIPTION) AS
  SELECT 5, 'aa', 'wheel chair' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'bl', 'blind' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| NEWID | HID | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 1 | 7 | 9 |
| 2 | 5 | 11 |
| 2 | 7 | 12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cCpTaasg)

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks as a cross join with `case` expression.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  reservation (rid, wheel_chair, blind) as
  3    (select 1,  8,  9 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 11, 12 from dual
  5    ),
  6  disability (hid, code, description) as
  7    (select 5, 'aa', 'wheel chair' from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'bl', 'blind'       from dual
  9    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 10  select r.rid as newid,
 11         d.hid,
 12         case when d.hid = 5 then r.wheel_chair
 13              when d.hid = 7 then r.blind
 14         end as count
 15  from reservation r cross join disability d;

     NEWID        HID      COUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          5          8
         1          7          9
         2          5         11
         2          7         12

SQL>
```

If you have to *insert* these rows into a new table, that should be fairly simple task to do so I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Here i dont want to hardcode the ids like 5 ,7 in the case

Comment: You'll have to hardcode *something*, will it be ID (5, 7) or names/descriptions ('wheel chair' or 'blind') (see MT0's answer with unpivot). Pick which you prefer.